# how to use the <br>tag in email content?

Tags: php, html

```
    $to      = "example@gmail.com" ;

$subject = "Instant estimate message";


$message ="<b>Name: </b>".$name."\r\n"."<b>Email: </b>".$email."\r\n"."<b>Mobile: </b>".$mobile."\r\n"."<b>Message: </b>".$message1;

$from = $email;
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

i cant get the details in newline, even i have added

`$message ="<b>Name: </b>".$name."</br>"."<b>Email: </b>".$email."</br>"."<b>Mobile: </b>".$mobile."</br>"."<b>Message: </b>".$message1;`

So tell me how to fix this.

Comment: `echo '<br>';` where you want a new line?

Comment: `\r\n` is for text emails... if you're creating an HTML email, then you obviously should use the HTML new line `<br>` or `<br/>`

Comment: how can i add echo in $message ="<b>Name: </b>".$name."</br>"."<b>Email: </b>".$email."</br>"."<b>Mobile: </b>".$mobile."</br>"."<b>Message: </b>".$message1;???

Comment: $message ="<b>Name: </b>".$name.echo "</br>"."<b>Email: </b>".$email."</br>"."<b>Mobile: </b>".$mobile."</br>"."<b>Message: </b>".$message1;?? this shows error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `<br/>` tag instead of `"\r\n"`. I think it may help you.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is your `<br />` tag. Be careful where to put the slash. Not before br but after it. Rikesh told you the correct way!

Answer (score 3):

Use `<br/>` tag,

```
$message =  "<b>Name: </b> $name <br/>".
            "<b>Email: </b> $email <br/>".
            "<b>Mobile: </b> $mobile <br/>".
            "<b>Message: </b> $message1";
```